# Convert string on specific logic

Tags: php

I would like to transfer a specific link to another. The patterns looks like this:

`http://domain.com/sub/code/name` to `http://a.domain.com/subs/code/name`

I need `a` one letter prefix before domain, the `sub` will be plural `subs` and thats all, all the rest needs to be equal.

Of course the link can start with `http://`, `www`, `http://www`

Some mix of `substr_replace`, `strpos` and `explode`, I stucked more than 1 hour on this task, decided to ask it.

Comment: Did you trying anything yourself?

Comment: How would you like to transfer the specific links? I don't understand what you mean by "transfer".

Comment: Show the actual code you tried. Just pointing out PHP functions you used is pointless.

Comment: This looks like a job for `mod_rewrite` rules. As far as PHP functions go, look at `parse_url()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
function convertLink($str)
{
    //ensure a scheme exists
    if(strpos($str,'http://')===false&&strpos($str,'https://')===false)
    {
        $str='http://'.$str;
    }
    $parts=parse_url($str);
    $scheme=$parts['scheme'];
    $domain=$parts['host'];
    $path=array_key_exists('path',$parts)?$parts['path']:'';
    $query=array_key_exists('query',$parts)?('?'.$parts['query']):'';
    $fragment=array_key_exists('fragment',$parts)?('#'.$parts['fragment']):'';

    if(strpos($parts['host'],'www.')===0){$domain=substr($parts['host'],4);}
    if(array_key_exists('port',$parts)){$domain.=':'.$parts['port'];}
    if(strpos($path,'/sub/')===0){$path='/subs/'.substr($path,5);}
    return "{$scheme}://a.{$domain}{$path}{$query}{$fragment}";
}

$links=array();
$links[]='domain.com/sub/code/name';
$links[]='domain.com:20/sub/code/name';
$links[]='www.domain.com/sub/code/name';
$links[]='http://domain.com/sub/code/name';
$links[]='http://www.domain.com/sub/code/name';
$links[]='https://domain.com/sub/code/name';
$links[]='sub.domain.com/sub/code/name';
$links[]='domain.com/sub/code/name?a=1&b=2#c';

echo '<pre>';
foreach($links as $link)
{
    echo str_pad($link, 40,' ',STR_PAD_RIGHT).'=> '.convertLink($link)."\n";
}
echo '</pre>';
```

Output:

```
domain.com/sub/code/name                => http://a.domain.com/subs/code/name
domain.com:20/sub/code/name             => http://a.domain.com:20/subs/code/name
www.domain.com/sub/code/name            => http://a.domain.com/subs/code/name
http://domain.com/sub/code/name         => http://a.domain.com/subs/code/name
http://www.domain.com/sub/code/name     => http://a.domain.com/subs/code/name
https://domain.com/sub/code/name        => https://a.domain.com/subs/code/name
sub.domain.com/sub/code/name            => http://a.sub.domain.com/subs/code/name
domain.com/sub/code/name?a=1&b=2#c      => http://a.domain.com/subs/code/name?a=1&b=2#c
```

Comment: Thank you, sorry that i didn't ansvered yet. This actually solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```regex
/^((?:http://)|(?:http://www\.)|(?:www\.))(\w+)(\.\w+\/)([\w+_\-]+)(\/.*?)$/

#$1YOUR_STRING.$2$3SOMETHING_ELSE$5
```

RegExr example: http://regexr.com?38dn0

Comment: I actually wanted to implement this method first, but since im a newbie i couldn't. It throved me internal error, and debug mode was turned off on my local development area at that time. I will definitely check back on this method once I'll have time. Basicly I checked the example on preg_replace on man and it worked, when i replaced the regex with yours the error occured.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking is fairly vague so I assume by "transfer" you mean "replace with".  If that is the case, then you should look into Regular Expressions (or Regex).

Regular expressions are relatively universal, so when you learn them once, you can apply them with most languages.

In PHP, you can perform a Regex Replace with `preg_replace`, but it may help to read up a bit first on the different elements of patterns.

Relevant Links:

[preg_replace PHP Function](http://nz1.php.net/preg_replace)

[PCRE Regex Syntax](http://nz1.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php)

EDIT: The end result you are after can still be achieved using `strpos`, `explode` etc as you described, but Regexs will likely get you there faster.